# Storybookjs some addons.setConfig not working

Tags: storybook, angular-storybook

I'm running @storybook/angular": "5.3.14"

My addons.js file:

```
addons.setConfig({
  showNav: false,
  showPanel: false,
  toolbar: {
    title: { hidden: true },
    zoom: { hidden: true },
    eject: { hidden: true },
    copy: { hidden: true },
    fullscreen: { hidden: true },
    'storybook/background': { hidden: true },
    'storybook/viewport': { hidden: true },
  },
});
```

`showNav: false` `showPanel: false` - these two settings are correctly hiding the left nav and panel but the `toolbar` setting is not working. I continue to see the toolbar buttons
[image]

StorybookJS is not my forté here, I've inherited a project. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?